# send more than 1 image with twilio and flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio, whatsapp, send

hi i'm new in flask and twilio, i'm try to send 2 images with 1 request but just appears the last image that i put in the array

this is my code

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Fetch the message
    msg = request.form.get('Body')

    # CLIENT 
    client = Client(os.getenv("TWILIO_ID"), os.getenv("AUTH_TOKEN"))
    number = request.values.get('From', '')
    #  creating the message
    if msg == "imagen":
        message = client.messages.create(
                                from_='whatsapp:+14155238886',
                                media_url=["https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png", "https://demo.twilio.com/bunny.png"],
                                to=number
                            )
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        resp.message("imagen : {}".format(message.body))
        return str(resp)
```

how could see in the "media_url" parameter i put 2 urls, but twilio just send my 1, i made a mistake?. i try it in this way too

```
        mss = MessagingResponse()
        resp = mss.message("this is a message")
        resp.body("imagen1")
        resp.media("https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png")
        resp.body("imagen2")
        resp.media("https://demo.twilio.com/bunny.png")
       
        return str(resp)
```

but is the same. thnks for ur help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. That code should work, it's just that there is no bunny image at that URL. You will need your image to be hosted at a publicly-accessible URL like these:

```py
 message = client.messages.create(
     from_="YOUR-TWILIO-NUMBER",
     to="NUMBER-TO-RECEIVE-IMAGES",
     body="Test sending two messages",
     media_url=["https://data.whicdn.com/images/339398954/original.gif", "https://thumbs.gfycat.com/PrestigiousUntidyBetafish-max-1mb.gif"],
 )
```

That returns this image:
[image: sms example received]
I'd recommend using [Twilio Runtime Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets), our static file hosting service that allows developers to quickly upload and serve the files needed to support their applications. host your files that support web, voice, and messaging applications. Assets is commonly used to host .mp3 audio files used in TwiML, to serve images sent through MMSes, or store configuration used by Twilio Functions. You can also deploy the images to be hosted on web servers.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: thnks for ur answer, but this doesn´t work for me, i'm using a trial version is that a problem for this ?

Comment: What's the error? Having a trial account shouldn't affect the code, but having an invalid URL/no image at the URL will

Comment: the images is in there, and works, the problem is that  just send me one of them

Comment: thnks for ur answer, the images works, i'm respond one-by-one and works fine, but using and array just send me the last image

Comment: when i run the code above i get both images

Comment: mmm, sorry, i'm was try it in ngrok. deploying in a web server works, thnks a lot.

Comment: ooh, will edit out ngrok--if it works, would appreciate it if you mark it as answer! 